# How to make a custom sheet size

Tags: header-footer

I'm formating a book and I need to use a size outside of the padron like a square page size or golden ratio but I don't know how to define a new norm for page size.

Comment: you can use the `geometry` package

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly easy using the `geometry` package. Here's an example which generates labels for a Dymo label printer.

```
% For the 11354 label
\documentclass[14pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=7.5mm,right=2mm,top=5mm,bottom=5mm,% 
paperwidth=57mm, paperheight=32mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{palatino}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Max Mustermann \\ Musterweg 1 \\ 12345~Musterstadt

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And how I make the marge be diferent for par and impar pages?

Comment: Look at https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Single_sided_and_double_sided_documents, you can set this using `oneside` or `twoside`